# always show error : 'DataFrame' object does not support item assignment in databricks

Tags: pandas, databricks

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = df_final_bureau_balance
df.show()
df.printSchema()
df["*"] = df['STATUS']
```

I wanna create one column but there is always one error:'DataFrame' object that does not support item assignment
but from pandas user manual there is nothing wrong.
the object does support item assignment isn't dataframe?

```
+------------+------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
|SK_ID_BUREAU|STATUS|max(MONTHS_BALANCE)|min(MONTHS_BALANCE)|count|
+------------+------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
|     5001709|     C|                  0|                -85|   86|
|     5001709|     X|                -86|                -96|   11|
|     5001710|     C|                  0|                -47|   48|
|     5001710|     X|                -49|                -82|   30|
|     5001710|     0|                -48|                -53|    5|
|     5001711|     X|                  0|                  0|    1|
|     5001711|     0|                 -1|                 -3|    3|
|     5001712|     C|                  0|                 -8|    9|
|     5001712|     0|                 -9|                -18|   10|
|     5001713|     X|                  0|                -21|   22|
|     5001714|     X|                  0|                -14|   15|
|     5001715|     X|                  0|                -59|   60|
|     5001716|     0|                -39|                -65|   27|
|     5001716|     X|                -66|                -85|   20|
|     5001716|     C|                  0|                -38|   39|
|     5001717|     0|                 -5|                -21|   17|
|     5001717|     C|                  0|                 -4|    5|
|     5001718|     C|                  0|                 -2|    3|
|     5001718|     X|                 -9|                -38|   10|
|     5001718|     0|                 -3|                -37|   24|
+------------+------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
only showing top 20 rows

root
 |-- SK_ID_BUREAU: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- STATUS: string (nullable = true)
 |-- max(MONTHS_BALANCE): integer (nullable = true)
 |-- min(MONTHS_BALANCE): integer (nullable = true)
 |-- count: long (nullable = true)

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object does not support item assignment
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2083632421660035> in <module>
      7 df.show()
      8 df.printSchema()
----> 9 df["*"] = df['STATUS']
     10 
     11 

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: are you sure that you're using Pandas dataframe? it looks like it's a Spark dataframe. you can use `df.toPandas()` to convert from Spark dataframe into Pandas dataframe

Comment: that works!!  thanks a lot @Alex Ott

Answer (score 0):

following syntaxs are not belong in panda dataframe. Those are related spark dataframe.

```
df.show()
df.printSchema()
```

Same functionality should be in panda dataframe,

```
print(df) 
df.info(verbose=True)
```

[image]

Comment: i find my problem....   the df is a Spark dataframe  :(   thank you for your answer!

Comment: thanks for your response . If you accept my answer , Kindly accept as accepted answer here.